# Vue import; which is better for performance

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-component

I've read multiple articles for Vue to split up the JS so it's smaller in filesize but I can't really figure out the difference between these 2 in terms of performance:

```
Modal: () => import(
                /* webpackChunkName: "js/partials/Alert" */
                /* webpackMode: "lazy" */
                /* webpackPrefetch: true */
                /* webpackPreload: true */
                '../../partials/Modal'
                ),
```

```
Modal: () => import('../../partials/Modal'),
```

Is there any difference at all? Why would it be better to use one or another?

Comment: Can you give any examples URLs where you have read those articles?